# SqlExceptionHelper, как включить LOG.isDebugEnabled() = true?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

При выполнении запроса в базу данных Postgres получаю сообщение, что одно из полей превышает длину 30 символов.

```
16:57:21 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(30)
```

Но, сам текст SQL-запроса, таблица и поле, содержащее ошибку, в лог не выводятся.
В классе SqlExceptionHelper.class есть метод  logExceptions  который при включенном  if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) по идее должен выводить текст SQL-запроса.

```
public void logExceptions( SQLException sqlException,
                           String message ) {
    if (LOG.isEnabled(Level.ERROR)) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            message = StringHelper.isNotEmpty(message) ? message : DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_MSG;
            LOG.debug( message, sqlException );
        }
```

Подскажите, как можно сделать LOG.isDebugEnabled() = true ?

https://github.com/ekirkilevics/Hibernate/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/spi/SqlExceptionHelper.java

Comment: что за объект этот LOG? Какого типа?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась исправлением в hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
```